# setSelectedNodes for jquery dynatree?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, dynatree, jquery-dynatree

I'm trying to select nodes on an existing dynatree using jquery/javascript, I googled quite a bit about it and read the documentation but couldn't find anything like setSelectedNodes so I can select nodes based on the selections!!

Am I missing something or dynatree just not support dynamic node selection using jquery/javascript!

Please help..

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure what you mean by this, but if you have a list of ID's and you want to select them in the tree you could do something like:

```
$.each( [selectorHere], function(i, item){
   var key=item.prop('someIdAttribute');
   $("#tree").dynatree("getTree").selectKey(key);
});
```